# fullcalendar change start and end for month view

Tags: fullcalendar, fullcalendar-5, jalali-calendar

I am working with Fullcalendar v5.* and I need to use Jalali calendar.
It seems that, I can not change the calendar to jalali, so I need to pass start and end date for month by hand. Is it possible to change start and end date in Monthlyview of Fullcalendar?

Comment: No, there isn't a way to do that. It always starts on the 1st of the month (in Gregorian calendar). There's an open issue about adding jalali support to fullCalendar here: https://github.com/fullcalendar/fullcalendar/issues/1813 - perhaps you could add your request to that so they know more people would like it.